# How to get integer from varchar data type using mysql function?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a function which return plan code when I give input plan title But my function not working please help me and correct my code. For example get_plan_tile_code(Break First) than it return me 1.I have also attached error file. I will be thankful to you.

```
Plan_code   Plan_title
1           Break First
2           Lunch
3           Dinner
```

```
id  Plan_title  Employee name
1   Break First   ABC
2   Lunch         DCF
3   Dinner        GHI
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_plan_tile_code(Actvi_SubPln_Title VARCHAR)RETURNS INT(99) 
BEGIN
DECLARE ATY_CODE INT(99) DEFAULT"";

  SELECT plan_id  INTO   ATY_CODE
  FROM   tbl_plan_scata
  WHERE  plan_sub_title = Actvi_SubPln_Title;
  
  RETURN ATY_CODE;
  
END //;
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Comment: @slaakso i think you already understand what i want pls tell me if you have soultion

Comment: The error message tells that VARCHAR datatype **must** have length definition.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the datatype declarations. Your `Actvi_SubPln_Title`-parameter is defined as `VARCHAR` with no length (you will need to define the length).

The function return value and the `ATY_CODE` -variable in the function on the other hand have length defined on `INT` (this is not needed). And datatype `INT` should not have `default ""` as it is not a string.

Comment: Additionally - the query may return not one row (both zero and over one).

Comment: @slaakso like that CREATE FUNCTION get_activity_tile_code(Actvi_SubPln_Title VARCHAR(400))

Comment: You may want to match the datatype of the `tbl_plan_scata.plan_sub_title` as you are comparing against it.